# ./waf: No such file or directory in NS3

Tags: linux, simulation, ns-3

```
~/ns-allinone-3.37/ns-3.37$ ./waf --run hello-simulator
bash: ./waf: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this problem?
All build.py results were successful.

`$ ./waf --run hello-simulator` 
*should provide an output such as*:

```
'build' finished successfully
Hello Simulator
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since ns-3.36, ns-3 has replaced Waf with CMake. https://www.nsnam.org/releases/ns-3-36/

You should now run the following to get the result you want.

```
./ns3 run hello-simulator
```